# Owl Carousel not working as expected

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I know this question is duplicated in Stack Overflow. I have been gone through lots of questions and answers in Stack Overflow as well as other site articles. How can I make my Owl-Carousel work?

The problem is simple, owl-carousel is not working. I followed the documentation as well as some answers provided in Stack Overflow.

I paste my code here.

```
<!-- cdn script imports-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<!-- cdn css import -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<!-- html -->
<div class="owl-carousal owl-theme">
  <div>
    slider 1
  </div>
  <div>
    slider 2
  </div>
  <div>
    slider 3
  </div>
  <div>
    slider 4
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spelling error change "***owl-carousal***" buy "***owl-carousel***" at

```
<div class="owl-carousal owl-theme"> <-------- owl-carousel not owl-carousal
<div>
  slider 1
</div>
 ...
```

here a working [pen](https://codepen.io/Knewtone/pen/MBXPMY)

Comment: Almost I wasted around 2 hours :-( Thank you so much friend